# Why are Selenium IDE playback controls inactive? (How can I run recorded tests?)

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I started learning how to use Selenium today. I have never used it before. I downloaded the Selenium IDE (1.0.10) plugin for FireFox (3.5.16). The way it's behaving is not matching up to the docs.

1. When I click the record button and perform actions in my browser, nothing happens in the IDE (nothing is recorded). (Actually, initially it did record, but now it doesn't) I tried restarting FireFox and that had no effect.
2. Also, the main controls are now inactive. I've included a screen shot to show what I mean by that. The controls remain inactive even it I click or double click on the name of a test case in the panel on the left.
3. And one final question -- it appears that a Selenium test case mentions Chrome in its default configuration even though the docs say you can only record tests using FireFox. Should I do anything about that?

If anyone can shed light on any of the above mysteries I would appreciate it. Thanks!

[image]

UPDATE

I restarted FireFox again and now it's recording actions, but the controls are still greyed-out as in the screenshot, so I can't play back the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not in the HTML runner mode. The IDE has no concept of ruby or python or c# or Java. That is up to plugins which just essentially do a find an replace.

*chrome means Firefox Chrome. Something that has been around for a lot longer than Google Chrome the browser. It means use the browser chrome which removes a couple sandboxing issues.

If you want to play back the tests you can't go out of the table mode otherwise the IDE won't understand what to do. The code in the screenshot should be stored in a .rb file and that should be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to unravel mysteries -

1. As soon as you launch the IDE it would be in recording mode. Do you see last Red button which is enabled.
2. IDE Tests can be executed only when in the selenese/html format (aka table format). I guess you have changed the format to ruby (I guess so), from Option > Format.
   To be able to execute tests change it back to html from option > Format > HTML
3. Take my words, IDE is only and only for firefox